# CommonFileDialog to return UNC path

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

The question is simple, can CommonFileDialog be forced to return paths exclusively in UNC format? E.g. the problem is when user selects a file on own machine using the dialog, path is relative. This means it won't work on a different machine within the same network.

How can this be overcome?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use your clients to store shared content - upload the files to your own network share.
But to your question you can manually convert c:.. to \hostname\c$.. if all users have admin privileges on all computers in the network.

Comment: I do agree with your comment, however it is not me who decide where data to be stored.

Comment: well I suppose you can get the file path and then [share its folder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4215/How-to-create-a-file-share-using-NET-framework). CommonFileDialog definitely don't have a built in property for that. BTW - always prefer fighting with your boss.